# Configure postfix to deliver faster when a mail got greylisted

Tags: postfix, debian-squeeze, greylisting

Where do I configure the time postfix waits until it tries to resend an email from the queue if an email was [grey-listed](http://projects.puremagic.com/greylisting/) on the recipient side?

I would like to configure it, so my server tries to resend the email after 2 Minutes if it was greylisted.

If the mail is in the queue for another reason, it can be longer.

Or is it the receiving server that defines the delay-time?

Also I would like to know [How long are the default times for greylisting with postgrey?](https://serverfault.com/questions/537195/how-long-are-the-default-times-for-greylisting)

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way of having a *variable* delay between resend attempts based on the reject reason?  I don't think that's currently possible but my knowledge of Postfix is not complete in this regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your settings for **minimal_backoff_time**, **maximum_backoff_time** and **queue_run_delay**.